# Flip Dataframe in R based on Dates?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) in the following format.

```
REGION BASIS_LOCATION CURVE_DATE    CONTRACT_BEGIN CONTRACT_END   FP
       x       y      2015-12-30    2016-02-01     2016-02-29     2
       x       y      2016-01-01    2016-02-01     2016-02-29     3
```

What I need to do is flip the table so the output is as follows

```
REGION BASIS  LOCATION  Date          2015-12-30   2016-01-01 
x              y        2016-02-01       2          3
x              y          .              .          .
x              y          .              .          .
x              y          .              .          .
x              y        2016-02-29       2          3
```

Trying to accomplish in [r](/questions/tagged/r).  Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map2` to create a sequence of 'Date' between the 'BEGIN', 'END' columns, then `unnest` to expand the dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with('CONTRACT')), ymd) %>% 
    mutate(DATE = map2(CONTRACT_BEGIN, CONTRACT_END, seq, by = 'day')) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = CURVE_DATE, values_from = FP) %>% 
    select(-c(CONTRACT_BEGIN, CONTRACT_END)) %>%
    unnest(c(DATE))
# A tibble: 29 x 5
#   REGION BASIS_LOCATION DATE       `2015-12-30` `2016-01-01`
#   <chr>  <chr>          <date>            <int>        <int>
# 1 x      y              2016-02-01            2            3
# 2 x      y              2016-02-02            2            3
# 3 x      y              2016-02-03            2            3
# 4 x      y              2016-02-04            2            3
# 5 x      y              2016-02-05            2            3
# 6 x      y              2016-02-06            2            3
# 7 x      y              2016-02-07            2            3
# 8 x      y              2016-02-08            2            3
# 9 x      y              2016-02-09            2            3
#10 x      y              2016-02-10            2            3
# … with 19 more rows
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(REGION = c("x", "x"), BASIS_LOCATION = c("y", 
"y"), CURVE_DATE = c("2015-12-30", "2016-01-01"),
CONTRACT_BEGIN = c("2016-02-01", 
"2016-02-01"), CONTRACT_END = c("2016-02-29", "2016-02-29"), 
    FP = 2:3), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: This looks like it's working.  Except the values show up as <dbl>. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: @TimBatten It is just a `tbl_df` print output method.  If you want to change it to data.frame just do `%>% as.data.frame` at the end

Comment: I still get the same <dbl> in the output even when I convert to a dataframe

Comment: Warning message:
Values in `FP` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list(FP = list)` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = list(FP = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = list(FP = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates

Comment: @TimBatten It is a print attribute of `tbl_df`.  It would be gone if you convert to `data.frame` (as I can't reproduce it)

Comment: Is there a way to use reshape instead to accomplish this?

Comment: @TimBatten You meant the `reshape` from `base R`.  It can be done but it is much more difficult to understand than pivot_wider